# Trying to save sheet 2 of a workbook on the desktop as CSV

Tags: csv, excel, save, vba

This function, when clicked on should ideally copy all of worksheet 2 to another workbook and save that sheet as a csv file.  its not working... and i don't know how to tell it where to save the file (i want it to save to desktop). help please?

Is there any easier way i can do this?

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()


'save as csv'

fname = "cambs_uploader.csv"
Sheet2.SaveAs fname, xlCSV


End Sub
```

Comment: Try this instead `fname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "cambs_uploader.csv"` . Kindly save the file before you run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's as simple as saving to your desktop every time then you can just put the full path in the string, rather than just the file name. However, if you want to save it by selection from a directory tree, then the easiest way in Excel is to use its Application.GetSaveAsFilename() method.

Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195734.aspx

Example:

```
Sub CommandButton2_Click()
   Dim fName As String
   Dim saveSheet As Worksheet

   Set saveSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") ' Change your sheet name

   saveSheet.SaveAs Application.GetSaveAsFilename("cambs_uploader.csv", ".csv", 1, "Save File")

   Set saveSheet = Nothing
Exit Sub
```